# forcing re-authenticate with existing user session using msal.js

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

in my next js application after user signup and redirect to my app their are steps they have to complete for requirement after they complete those steps from my backend using azure ad graph api i am updating the user claims so i need to expire the session and force to re-authenticate with existing user session without any user input so i can extract those claims from new token. how can i re-authenticate user in this way?

```
acquireTokenSilent()
```

always retrieve access token from cached

Answer (score 0):

To expire the session and force to re-authenticate with the existing user session, you could directly logout AAD and then clear the cache.

Comment: i cleared the idtoken and access token form cache using `clearCacheForScope(scope)` and then use `acquireTokenSilent(scope)` it worked but not every time new claims comes with it. i also wait for 8 sec and then start `acquireTokenSilent(scope)` same result. some time i get the new claims and some time i didn't

Comment: For this, you could use the [single sign-out](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-protocols-openid-connect-code#single-sign-out). Upon you log out, it will automatically clear the session cookie.

Comment: does Azure AD B2C - Applications have those attribute i can't find **Click on Settings, then Properties and find the Logout URL text box**

Comment: Sorry for this, in the b2c, cannot set the single sign-out.